# gh-pages not allowing multiple subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain, godaddy, cname, multi-subdomains

I am following the Github Pages tutorial. I thought I could have two domains: `api.website.com` and `website.com`, and the first is created via a folder called `api` in my main website folder where `index.html` is stored.

When I type in `website.com` as a subdomain, it says my site is ready to be published at `http://website.com` which is great. However I also want to have the domain `http://api.website.com` as an additional one, yet it overwrites the existing subdomain `http://website.com`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Steps I thought I would follow:

1. https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-removing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/
2. https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-subdomain/
3. https://medium.com/@LovettLovett/github-pages-godaddy-f0318c2f25a#.ae41mob6t

Comment: [There is already a solution about that](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42455/publishing-more-than-one-site-on-github-pages)

Comment: @Goyllo that is fantastic. Sorry I did try hard to find solutions. For the sake of the community just post an answer and I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create another repository for github pages for example `api.github.io` .Which is accessible from github.com/yourusername/api.github.io
2. [Create separate branch](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository/) with name `gh-pages`
3. Create a CNAME file which contain your subdomain name for example `api.example.com` then deploy it to your repository OR simply add your subdomain into custom domain filed. **Make sure the branch is gh-pages**
4. Configure CNAME records in your domain panel. For example host name is your subdomain `api` which point to your repository name `api.github.io`
5. [Configure A records](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider) which point to github pages server.
6. Deploy your index.html and other file to your repository, **make sure** you push to `gh-pages` branch. For example `git push origin gh-pages`